# How to get Menu Item Enabled Status in Pywinauto?

Tags: python, user-interface, automation, pywinauto

I want to select the menu item `Log`  In in File and check if it is enabled or no. I tried using menu_select but not able to get. Also used py_inspect.py to get a tree there we can find the app status if it enabled how to get. Please find below an image of `py_inspect.py` application control id tree.
[py_inspect.py app tree Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wod81.png), I want to popup image to the user if the application is logged out. If login is disabled I want to select menu item `order->placeOrder` and open order window.

```
from pywinauto import Application
import time
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import Desktop

windows = Desktop(backend="uia").windows()
print([w.window_text() for w in windows])
window_title = "Trader"
app = Application().connect(title=window_title)

top_window = app.top_window()
top_window_name = top_window.window_text()
print("Top Window of App -  " + top_window_name)

if top_window_name == "Log In":
    print("Top Window is Log In")
elif top_window_name == window_title:
    print("Main Window is On Top")
else :
    print("Not Top Window Found")

top_window.dump_tree(depth=2)
```

Tried with adding ...

```
login_status = top_window.Menubar.File.Log_In.element_info.enabled()
```

But not sucessfull.